# Как использовать DbCobtext в миграциях?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, миграция

Привет. У меня возникла необходимость использовать DbContext в миграциях. Как можно получить его не создавия заново (ну или хотябы получить connection string и создать контекст используя ее). Использую EF Core. Пример:

```
namespace Data.SqlServer.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(MyDbContext))] // i want use this context
    [Migration("CustomMigration_DataSeed")]
    public partial class DataSeedMigration : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            // add some entities
            _context.User.Add(new User());
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

класс `Configuration` метод `Seed(AppContext context)` - не подойдет?